# Why does Incrementing a size_t default value giving garbage value?

Tags: c++

Why does Incrementing a `size_t` default value giving garbage value?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Test {
  size_t a;
  size_t b;
};

int main() {
  Test wrong;
  cout << (wrong.a) ++;
  cout << endl;
  cout << (wrong.b) ++;

  cout << endl;

  Test right {};
  cout << (right.a) ++;
  cout << endl;
  cout << (right.b) ++;

  return 0;
}
```

For the above code getting output

```
Output:

93937114642880
93937114642304
0
0
```

Is this because `size_t` not a POD? Also why does the `Test wrong;` not calling the default constructor and initialises the fields to default values?

Comment: Because you never initialized those values in the 1st case?

Comment: More accurate than "caused by a typo", I'm certain there is a duplicate describing the difference between `Thing;` and `Thing{};`.  Or perhaps asker can clarify what they think "`size_t` default value" means.

Comment: The increment isn't relevant. Take it out. Same problem.

Comment: I was confused since both `size_t a;` and `size_t b{};` gives 0 as initial value

Comment: @vrnithinkumar: In which case you have a kind compiler. Out of interest try `{size_t a = -1;} size_t a;` and see what `a` is then. Will likely be different values between "debug" and "optimised" builds.

Comment: @vrnithinkumar "*`size_t a;` ... gives 0 as initial value*" - that is not guaranteed, it is *undefined behavior* since `a` is uninitialized in that case. On the other hand, `size_t b{};` is guaranteed to give `0`.

Comment: @vrnithinkumar until you become very familiar with [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), the "try it and see what happens" approach is **not reliable** in C++.

Comment: For all "built-in" types (`int`, `double`, `size_t`, etc), accessing the value of an uninitialised variable gives undefined behaviour.  Default initialisation in your case is leaving those `size_t`s uninitialised.   It is not possible to increment a `size_t` without accessing its value, so incrementing an uninitialised `size_t` gives undefined behaviour.  One possible symptom of undefined behaviour is producing garbage values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does Incrementing a `size_t` default value giving garbage value?

You need to be very careful with your terminology. `default` has specific meaning in C++.

In your first case, the `size_t` variables in `wrong` are NOT being given *default* values. You are incrementing *uninitialized* variables that have *indeterminate* values.  This is **undefined behavior**.  So, you get garbage output because you are acting on garbage values to begin with.

In your second case, you are *value-initializing* the `size_t` variables in `right` to `0` before then incrementing them, which is **well-defined behavior**.  And since you are using the *post-increment* `++` operator, which returns the *previous* value before it is incremented, that is why the output is `0` rather than `1`.

> Is this because `size_t` not a POD?

No.  `size_t` is a POD type.

> Also why does the `Test wrong;` not calling the default constructor and initialises the fields to default values?

`Test wrong;` performs [**default initialization**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization).  It *does* call the default constructor, but you simply didn't implement that constructor yourself, so the compiler auto-generates one for you.  And since all of the members are PODs, there is nothing for the generated constructor to do, so it doesn't initialize the members at all.

`Test right{};` performs [**value initialization**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), which in this case will zero out the `size_t` members.

Comment: Glad we re-opened the question: this is a nice answer indeed.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour of reading the `struct` members after `Test wrong;` is undefined. This is because they are not initialised. As such they hold indeterminate values. `++` requires a read of the object being incremented; so `(wrong.a)++;` is the first undefined statement reached. Formally this means that the behaviour of the *entire program* is undefined!

`Test right{};` *does* value-initialise the members, which has the effect of setting them to zero.

Comment: Technically, `Test right{};` does not default-initialize, it [value-initializes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), which happens to set the `size_t` members to `0`s in this case.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Oops - even an old cat like me confuses the various initialisation terms. Thank you.

Comment: See [Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization).

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Indeed. I should stick it to the inside of my lavatory door, alongside the operator precedence table.